# How to cancel webapi bulit in parse response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

first its something that happening in webapi 2.2 and not in the old one
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-2-1-web-apis/

> I get from webapi response

```
{
    "ProductValue": [
        "The input was not valid."
    ]
}
```

> how i cancel this response and just get false in

`ModelState.IsValid`

> i need to return more fields to response
>
> and this response is not good for me
>
> for those who have hard trouble to understand in dubug i dont enter to
>   this function at all,because web api built in mechanism 
>   return his response instend of mine 
>   {code=9}

```
public MyResponse Start(Request req)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return new MyResponse(){code=0} ;
    }
     return new MyResponse(){code=9} ;
}
```

Comment: Dude this needs so much more information, you don't even know. Can we get a code sample? Most likely, you're passing the wrong type in to the controller and webapi is binning that bit

Comment: like i wrote, this is webapi response and not mine, i want to cancel bulit in response and return mine if model not valid

Comment: Do you have access to the Web API code?

Comment: like i said before, the response is web api built in mechanism, in debug i dont step in function because web api built in mechanism response return his response, maybe its a webapi core2 thing

Comment: Like @Stuart.Sklinar said, we're going to need [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-2-1-web-apis/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#automatic-http-400-responses

Comment: What data are you sending in/

Comment: I know what the answer is to this, but the quality of the question is horrendous. Fix the question and I will post a full and complete answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
services.AddMvc()
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;

    });
```

> thanks to Kirk Larkin

Comment: This isnt correct. This just simply bypasses the built in mechanism, it doesnt actually replace or return a different response when the model state is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Not absolutely sure what you are trying to achieve but if you want to send your own custom error response then you can probably do something like below (Hypothetically)

```
Product p = GetProduct(productvalue);
if (p == null)
{
    HttpError err = new HttpError($"Product with productvalue {productvalue} not found");
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, err);
}
else
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, p);
}
```